# Dynamically call a method in a module?

Tags: ruby, methods, module

How can I dynamically call a method in a module?

```
module Notification
  def self.send_notification(title, message)
    puts title + message
  end
end

def test(string)
  p string
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  send("test", 'hello from test')
  send("Notification.send_notification", 'hello', 'there') # Error: undefined method `Notification.send' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
end
```

Edit:
  I have more than one Module in my library and I really need to be able to convert a string to the module name. Say I also have a Module called Email. Maybe Eval is the only way? 
Edit2:
Renamed method in order not to conflict with built in send-method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see the only way, if you wish to get a module by name defined as a `String`, and don't use the `#eval`:

```
Object.const_get( 'Notification' ).send( 'send_notification', 'hello', 'there' )
# hellothere
```

If you wish to use `#eval` that is strongly non-recommended in many cases:

```
eval( 'Notification' ).send( 'send_notification', 'hello', 'there' )
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for.